# Pgfplot: remove tick elements on axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am trying to plot a graph using pgfplots. The plot is fine, my only concern is about the fact that I don't have, let's say, a linear x axis: I have the following elements: 1,2,4,5,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,15,20. These are ID number to identify some experiment.

Thus, when I plot them, there is space between 5 and 7 (the plot of course is expecting a 6) or between 15 and 20. I would like to have no space between x tick elements, as highlighted in the attached image.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
n,c1,c2
1,0,64
2,98,93
4,0,8
5,88,98
7,91,19
9,97,97
10,84,99
12,30,94
13,95,91
14,95,97
15,83,91
20,99,99
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
width=\textwidth,
height=\axisdefaultheight,
xlabel={x label},
ylabel={y label},
xtick={1,2,4,5,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,15,20}
]

\addplot[thick, blue, mark=o] table[x=n, y=c1, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\addplot[thick, green, mark=triangle] table[x=n, y=c2, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use the same technique as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346558/histogram-in-latex-with-random-x-axis-values/346649#346649

Comment: thanks! I provided the code as answer...thanks again!

Comment: that one was the solution. I misunderstood your previous comment

Comment: @clfmaris My comment was badly written, sorry. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

@Torbjørn T. : thanks a lot! It works...

I tried with both csv and dat format; with csv something "strange" happens:
if I write

```
xticklabels from table={data.csv}{n},
```

while using csv format, it gives me error:

> Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, could not retrieve column 'col sep
>   comma, n' from table 'data.csv'.

and I solved using

instead of

```
xticklabels from table={data.dat}{n},
```

of course I changed my code using .dat format

I provide both the solutions.

**dat format**

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
n c1 c2
1 0 64
2 98 93
4 0 8
5 88 98
7 91 19
9 97 97
10 84 99
12 30 94
13 95 91
14 95 97
15 83 91
20 99 99
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
enlarge x limits=0.01, % adjust space between axis edge and plot edge
xticklabels from table={data.dat}{n}, % use the x column from the file for ticklabels
xtick=data, % add a tick at every data point,
width=\textwidth,
height=\axisdefaultheight,
xlabel={x label},
ylabel={y label}%,
]

\addplot[thick, blue, mark=o] table[x expr=\coordindex, y=c1] {data.dat};
\addplot[thick, green, mark=triangle] table[x expr=\coordindex, y=c2] {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**csv format**

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
n,c1,c2
1,0,64
2,98,93
4,0,8
5,88,98
7,91,19
9,97,97
10,84,99
12,30,94
13,95,91
14,95,97
15,83,91
20,99,99
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
xticklabels from table={data.dat}{n}, % pay attention to .dat
xtick=data,
width=\textwidth,
height=\axisdefaultheight,
xlabel={x label},
ylabel={y label}
]

\addplot[thick, blue, mark=o] table[x expr=\coordindex, y=c1, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\addplot[thick, green, mark=triangle] table[x expr=\coordindex, y=c2, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```